# Including a file in all folders with same link

Tags: php

I am trying to include a connect file values one level above the public_html level(not my idea).

I'd like to have one connect file in the public_html root that includes the link and can use the values to connect to the db but I haven't been able to - so I use a connect file in each folder root.

I've attempted using dynamic links like:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/filename.php
```

but the only way I can get to that include

```
../filename.php
```

OR if it's inside a folder I need to make the include link :

```
../../filename.php
```

Any ideas?

EDIT :

both have worked for me

```
include "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/../filename.php";

dirname($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
include "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/../filename.php";
```

This starts from the document root, then uses `..` to go up one level up from there.

Comment: That's the intended pathname.

Comment: interesting, I wasn't aware that format worked. Thanks! - I can't upvot your comment bc I'm new

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? Every directory contains a `..` entry that points to its parent. It's there precisely to allow this syntax to work.

Comment: I'm not sure, just never used it besides the start of a path before - I appreciate your help.

Comment: You should learn how things work, don't just copy what you've seen.